# How can I restrict the predicted values of a bayesian linear regression?

Tags: regression, bayesian

Is there a way to restrict the predicted values, say, to only positive values or an interval of values? Let's say I want to estimate a linear model, y = a + Xb, using Bayesian techniques. I specify priors for a and b, a ~ Normal(0, 1), b ~ Normal(0,1). When estimating posteriors, I might get that b= -0.3 with some probability and a = 0.2 . What I want to do is to restrict the values of y to be positive always after replacing the values of a and b in the above equation, y = 0.2 - 0.3X. Here the value of X is always fixed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Stan allows you to put priors on transformations of the parameters, so you could put a half-normal prior on $a + Xb$.  See https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/putting-priors-on-transformed-parameters.  Stan effectively backpropagates priors on transformed quantities to priors on parameters.

But make sure that a model that needs a positivity override is the best choice of model.  [Semiparametric models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) automatically respect the distribution of $Y$ including handling things like "clumping at zero".